# Нужно вывести древовидную структуру многомерного массива объектов

Tags: javascript, ооп

Есть массив обьектов:

```js
var testObject = [
    {
        name: 'Название 1',
        value: 2,
        childnodes: [
            {
                name: 'Название 4',
                value: 25,
                childnodes: [
                    {
                        name: 'Название 9',
                        value: 32,
                        childnodes: [
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Название 10',
                        value: 0,
                        childnodes: [
                            {
                                name: 'Название 11',
                                value: 5,
                                childnodes: [
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'Название 12',
                                value: 2267,
                                childnodes: [
                                    {
                                        name: 'Название 15',
                                        value: 35,
                                        childnodes: [
                                            {
                                                name: 'Название 16',
                                                value: 55,
                                                childnodes: [
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'Название 5',
                value: 12,
                childnodes: [
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'Название 6',
                value: 45,
                childnodes: [
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Название 2',
        value: 32,
    },
    {
        name: 'Название 3',
        value: 7,
        childnodes: [
            {
                name: 'Название 7',
                value: 12334,
                childnodes: [
                    {
                        name: 'Название 13',
                        value: 122,
                        childnodes: [
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'Название 8',
                value: 86,
                childnodes: [
                    {
                        name: 'Название 14',
                        value: 222,
                        childnodes: [
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Задание состоит в том чтоб с помощью знаков псевдографики вывести древовидную структуру обьекта типа:

```js
// ├ Название 1
// │ ├ Название 4
// │ │ ├ Название 9
// │ │ └ Название 10
// │ │ ├ Название 11
// │ │ └ Название 12
// │ │ └ Название 15
// │ │ └ Название 16
// │ ├ Название 5
// │ └ Название 6
// ├ Название 2
// └ Название 3
// ├ Название 7
// │ └ Название 13
// └ Название 8
// └ Название 14
```

Что я "нашаманил" на данный момент:

```js
var symbols = Array("├", "│", "└"); //массив символов в качестве префикса для значений

function buildItem(item){
     
  var сontainer = item.name+ "\n";

    if( item.childnodes ) {

        for (var i = 0; i < item.childnodes.length; i++){ 
   if (i < item.childnodes.length-1 && item.childnodes.length!==0) container += ( symbols[0]+ buildItem(item.childnodes[i]));
   else container+=(symbols[2] + buildItem(item.childnodes[i]));
        };
  container+=symbols[1];

    }
 
    
    return container;
}
 var content = Array();
 
 for (var i = 0; i < testObject.length; i++) {
    content[i] = buildItem(testObject[i]);
};
var str = content.join("\n");
console.log(str);
```

Результат:

```js
Название 1
├ Название 4
├ Название 9
│ └ Название 10
├ Название 11
│ └ Название 12
└ Название 15
└ Название 16
│ │ │ │ │ ├ Название 5
│ └ Название 6
│ │ 
Название 2

Название 3
├ Название 7
└ Название 13
│ │ └ Название 8
└ Название 14
│ │ │
```

Тоесть работает код не совсем так, как хотелось бы, даже не так как надо. 
Суть вопроса: я вроде как и ошибку понимаю, что в первом вызове функции в принципе все хорошо, но последующая рекурсия не дает желаемого результата;
прошу обьясните где я ошибаюсь, буду очень благодарен

Comment: Вам нужно передавать в рекурсивную функцию еще один параметр "_глубину вложенности_". Этот параметр должен влиять на _количество_ отрисовываемых вертикальных линий. При каждом вызове рекурентной функции этот параметр должен увеличиваться на единицу.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую осознать и сделать))

Comment: еще вопросик, можно ли вообще считать мое решение хоть более-менее оптимальным?))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При печати очередного узла, перед ним нужно напечать префикс, который будет содержать связи его предков с их сиблингами. Можно заметить 2 вещи:

1. Для всех детей одного узла префикс будет один и тот же, поэтому его можно накапливать в параметре рекурсивной процедуры;
2. Если узел является последним ребенком, то для него линию вниз рисовать не нужно.

Получается как-то так:

```
function buildTree(tree, prefix) {
  if (typeof prefix === 'undefined')
    prefix = '';
  var result = '';
  tree.forEach(function(e, i) {
    var lastNode = i == tree.length - 1;
    result += prefix + (lastNode ? '└' : '├') + ' ' + e.name + '\n';
    if (e.childnodes)
      result += buildTree(e.childnodes, prefix + (lastNode ? ' ' : '|') + ' ');
  });
  return result;
}
```

Результат:

```
├ Название 1
| ├ Название 4
| | ├ Название 9
| | └ Название 10
| |   ├ Название 11
| |   └ Название 12
| |     └ Название 15
| |       └ Название 16
| ├ Название 5
| └ Название 6
├ Название 2
└ Название 3
  ├ Название 7
  | └ Название 13
  └ Название 8
    └ Название 14
```

```js
function buildTree(tree, prefix) {
  if (typeof prefix === 'undefined')
    prefix = '';
  var result = '';
  tree.forEach(function(e, i) {
    var lastNode = i == tree.length - 1;
    result += prefix + (lastNode ? '└' : '├') + ' ' + e.name + '\n';
    if (e.childnodes)
      result += buildTree(e.childnodes, prefix + (lastNode ? ' ' : '|') + ' ');
  });
  return result;
}

var testObject = [{
  name: 'Название 1',
  value: 2,
  childnodes: [{
    name: 'Название 4',
    value: 25,
    childnodes: [{
      name: 'Название 9',
      value: 32,
      childnodes: []
    }, {
      name: 'Название 10',
      value: 0,
      childnodes: [{
        name: 'Название 11',
        value: 5,
        childnodes: []
      }, {
        name: 'Название 12',
        value: 2267,
        childnodes: [{
          name: 'Название 15',
          value: 35,
          childnodes: [{
            name: 'Название 16',
            value: 55,
            childnodes: []
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Название 5',
    value: 12,
    childnodes: []
  }, {
    name: 'Название 6',
    value: 45,
    childnodes: []
  }, ]
}, {
  name: 'Название 2',
  value: 32,
}, {
  name: 'Название 3',
  value: 7,
  childnodes: [{
    name: 'Название 7',
    value: 12334,
    childnodes: [{
      name: 'Название 13',
      value: 122,
      childnodes: []
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Название 8',
    value: 86,
    childnodes: [{
      name: 'Название 14',
      value: 222,
      childnodes: []
    }]
  }]
}];

document.body.innerHTML = buildTree(testObject).split('\n').join('<br/>');
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: оооо, огромное спасибо, я уже почти к этому дошел, но доходил бы я ооочень долго) ещё раз огромное человеческое СПАСИБО)) буду вникать в Ваше решение и смотреть где был неправ)

Comment: блин а всё в самом деле куда проще, чем я тут расписываю)))

Comment: крч усёк, что не шарил forEach(), спасибо, что чудесно ознакомили меня с этой функцией JS